# How I can get the first subdomain of target site in a proxy which use plain urls

Tags: javascript, regex, url, uri

If someone wants the last subdomain of the current site *(ex : get`ftp`in`ftp.kernel.org`)*, one can use

```
location.hostname.split('.')[0]
```

However, with a non obfuscating proxy, a URL can be like this`http://www.someproxy.com/somepath_layers/site.bin?http://ftp.kernel.org/pub/iso`.
Then,`location.hostname`will return the proxy address.`location.pathname`would strip the target address, so I only see a plain`location.href`.

The point is to strip before after`http://` but if the proxy is also accessible securely the URL become`https://www.someproxy.com/somepath_layers/site.bin?http://ftp.kernel.org/pub/iso`

So, how I can match until last pattern occurrence included in JavaScript? (the purpose is to make the site working inside web.archive.org liveweb).

**Update** : I also need the regex to work without a proxy *(when accessing the site directly)*.

Comment: Every proxy has different syntax, I don't think you can make a general rule.

Comment: @Barmar : I said in my question I want to make things works only with web.archive.org or proxies which repeat the targeted site full URL like [this](http://www.corsproxy.com/) or [this](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/).

Answer (score 0):

This regex extracts the first subdomain:

```
/(?!(?:https?|ftps?):\/\/)\b([a-z][^.]+).*/ig
```

The subdomain is in capturing group 1

[See regex](https://www.regex101.com/r/vR2vB4/3)

Comment: I think I should use this with`location.href.match()`isn’t it? Your link return`www`with`https://www.someproxy.com/somepath_layers/site.bin?http://ftp.kernel.org/pub/iso`instead of`ftp`